# TypeScript partial of a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to define a type as a mix of explicit properties and a generic type, with the explicit properties taking precedence in case of matching keys. Below is my attempt but I'm getting an error on the line indicated - can anyone explain why or is this a tsc/compiler bug?

```
// Takes properties in A and B. For matching properties, the types in A are used.
type Mix<A, B> = {
  [K in keyof B | keyof A]: K extends keyof A
    ? A[K]
    : K extends keyof B
    ? B[K]
    : never
}

type Versionable = { version: number }

function test<T>(): void {
  const version1: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>>['version'] = 1 // compiles - version type is correctly inferred as number | undefined
  const version2: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>>['version'] = undefined // compiles
  const version3: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>>['version'] = '1' // does not compile as expected

  const obj1: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>> = { version: 1 } // DOES NOT COMPILE.... WHY??
  const obj2: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>> = { version: undefined } // compiles
  const obj3: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>> = { version: '1' } // does not compile as expected
  const obj4: Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>> = {} // compiles
  obj4.version = 1 // compiles
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Looks like problem is with generic T, as everyting works for static type set. First thought is that the problem is with probably intersection between A and B which cannot be solved by compiler if B is unknown. Tried such type, and no luck for now:
`type Mix<A, B> = {
  [K in keyof A]: A[K]
} & {
  [K in Exclude<keyof B, keyof A>]: B[K]
}
`

Comment: The question is what sense has such structure, as we know you cannot in the body of `test` function put any property of T, as it is unknown at this level. It means that this function always works with just `Partial<Versionable>` type. Can you share what is the purpose of type T here?

Comment: Another version of the same type would be - `type Mix<A, B> = A & Pick<B, Exclude<keyof B, keyof A>>`. But the question remains was is the purpose of type T inside `test`

Comment: Hi, in short I have an API that is parameterised with a generic type T but it has certain requirements of T, like being versionable. But T extends { version: number } for example won't cut it because I can't then do a partial of T and set it to { version: 1 } when specifying a filter/where clause for example. (because in T version might be extended to be a more specific type than number, say only the numbers 2 and 3, and the compiler therefore won't let me set it to 1). I therefore need a type that is all of T except for properties I require. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behavior here is the same as in [microsoft/TypeScript#13442](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442); almost no concrete values are seen by the compiler as assignable to `Partial<SomethingDependingOnAGenericTypeParam>` except for ones with properties of type `undefined` (this is responsible for `obj2`'s behavior) or an empty object (this is responsible for `obj4`'s behavior).

This restriction is usually a defensible one because often these assignments are unsafe:

```
function unsafeCaught<T extends { a: string }>() {
  const nope: Partial<T> = { a: "" }; // CORRECT error  
}
interface Oops { a: "someStringLiteralType" };
unsafeCaught<Oops>(); // {a: ""} is not a valid Partial<Oops>
```

(this is responsible for `obj3`'s behavior.)  But the restriction also prevents certain known-safe ones, like yours, which has been specifically crafted:

```
function safeCaught<T extends { a: string }>() {
  const stillNope: { [K in keyof T]?: K extends "a" ? string : T[K] }
    = { a: "" }; // incorrect error
}
```

(this is responsible for `obj1`'s behavior.)  In these cases the compiler simply isn't performing the analysis necessary for this to work.  A [similar issue, microsoft/TypeScript#31070](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31070) was actually considered to be a bug and fixed, but in that case the mapped property type was a constant like `number` whereas in yours it's a conditional type.  And the compiler already does a rather poor job of verifying assignability to conditional types that depend on unresolved generic parameters.  So for your case I'd chalk this up to a design limitation of TypeScript and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to establish that you know better than the compiler in this case:

```
const obj1 = { version: 1 } as Partial<Mix<Versionable, T>>; // okay now
```

---

Oddly enough, this restriction is loosened when you write to a property instead of assigning an object to the variable, so you end up with the very same unsound behavior with no error:

```
function unsafeUncaught<T extends { a: string }>(val: Partial<T>) {
  val.a = ""; // uh, wait
}
const oops: Oops = { a: "someStringLiteralType" };
unsafeUncaught(oops);
```

I'm [not sure why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33134#issuecomment-526202753) but it's probably a design decision somewhere.  And therefore the following also gives you no error, but only coincidentally, since it's not properly checking in the first place:

```
function safeUncaught<T extends { a: string }>(
  val: { [K in keyof T]?: K extends "a" ? string : T[K] }
) {
  val.a = ""; // okay but coincidentally
}
```

This is probably why your `version1`, `version2`, and `version3` work, as well as `obj4.version = 1`.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOAzgQ2AUwMJpAcwAsoAeAFUUwA8pMwATFRAb0TQC5EUoAnGMfIgC+APgAUAShYAoRIggJuiMHAAOmTgAU0PWGgA25EYgC8LNpwBEl4QG5EAegeJsAeQBK7gKLYKmHjxwPHLSQtL8tDzAaBCYiK5qTKwciJYocAC2mADKvPz4ADIwkQZkAJ7qNkK20qgYOHhEpAmqKOIS9k4sKdZCiDBMKlBsiABuBjD0iNq6MAYkLW2y0tKgkLAIXPW4BMTklDR0jOYp3HwCwu0ycgpgStww+voAcmoa5gDaANL9SADWmDKcGAiDIAF0APycH7UWgMJiWNA2CFcPIXThkb5g4SyOSmE5WKqdZz8BQBTDQSgBIKhFbSKAVOIAWRgVBIAEEADSIABCxjMzFx31+iABQJBPMQAB9RYDgYh2WDoQc4ccxfL2biUeysbjlbCjkx1RKtbzdXJOGBMKN-LT6YzEAA1fwoeBgNAAI30cQFYxdbstIAyHv8ONW4GgbsQtG4RkknFGcEm13kimGcA9ACsAIz41g2niuhCcXN9NBMGZ6QwstnOwtuz3e7lkEQiYmIOB-NBlZRwADudrp4fWUbqWAAqpBGns-Id4QTUedBKIxON9FodFWjFJBXI1wA6ND46ztkCEbl9tDFWm3JRwRKcRZ5iypdJZXJLoolfTlSp2Wp3PUk4QNOUBiPerQdCsayRps6ATlOuykLOqpJC+Zz5Jcq4GJwrDCvwsriqCkL6nOxyIsii6YRiWLCDuuIHkeZgno4zidt2iAeiAwwKKSkx0FABj6GUtJAA)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll chalk it up to a compiler bug then and say hello to my little friend.... any! ;)