# Why doesn't the type of the return value satisfy Partial<T>?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  kind: string
}
function m<T extends User>(u: T): Partial<T> {
  return {id: 1}
}
```

Since `{id:1}` is of type `{id:number}`, which is a subset of `T`, the code should work normally. But it throws an error saying that "Type `'{ id: 1; }'` is not assignable to type `'Partial<T>'`."

I can't figure out why the type infered result of `{id:1}` is `{id:1}` itself instead of `{id:number}`. But anyway, I can assert that it actually is of type `{id:number}`, like this:

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  kind: string
}
function m<T extends User>(u: T): Partial<T> {
  return {id: 1} as {id: number}
}
```

But still, it again throws an new error saying that "Type `'{ id: number; }'` is not assignable to type `'Partial<T>'`". Strangely, isn't `{id: number}` a subset of `T`?

So here I have several questions:

1. Why the type infered result of `{id:1}` is `{id:1}` itself instead of `{id:number}`?
2. Why it still throws an error even if I have asserted that `{id:1}` is of type `{id: number}`?
3. How can I make the code work normally?

Comment: "isn't `{ id: number }` a subset of `T`?" - I recommend against using set-theoretic terms (like "subset") when discussing type-theory. Type-theoreticians use the same words (like "union" and "product") but in very different way.

Comment: This looks like the same, if not very similar, problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279796/typescript-partial-of-a-generic-type

Comment: Hint: `m`'s return-type is `Partial<T>`, not `Partial<User>`, and `m` doesn't know what `T` is at compile-time.

Comment: IMHO, problems like this show that TypeScript is headed in a wrong direction. Instead of writing clean, readable, understandable code people get caught in these type-theory rabbit holes.

Comment: @Dai Yes, it doesn't know what T is. But it knows T extends User in advance. So it knows T must have id property and kind property.

Comment: Generally speaking SO posts should have one main question. I'm assuming question #2 is the main one here (since it aligns with your title). The answer to that is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980764/2887218); `T` can be a type like `{id: 100, kind: string}`, and then `{id: 1}` does not extend `Partial<T>`.  Q#1: the compiler always uses literal types like `1` and then decides to widen to nonliteral types like `number` in some circumstances.

Comment: Q#3 depends on what "normally" means; want to suppress errors? Write `{id: 1} as Partial<T>` Want type safety? Change the signature to non-generic like `function m(u: User): {id: number}` instead.  Need generics and don't want type assertions? You'll need to describe the use case more (and probably in a different question post, since again, it's better to have one question per post)

Comment: @jcalz Ah yes - I keep on forgetting that TypeScript considers different product-types as incompatible when other languages with traditional inheritance would consider them compatible _despite_ TS basis in structural-typing (....I think?)