# Typescript strange parameter type inferrence error between 2 functions

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typescript-generics

I have a simple situation that should be quite straight forward, but a have a strange type issue that i think type inferring is to blame for:

```
// this type accepts any of T's property with the same value type,
// or the '_id' property with a string value type
type TTest<T extends object> = { [TProp in keyof T]?: TProp extends '_id' ? string : T[TProp] }

interface Deletable {
  _deletedAt?: Date
}

function f1<T extends Deletable>(): void {
  f2<T>({ _deletedAt: new Date() })
}

function f2<T extends Deletable>(param: TTest<T>): void {
  console.log(param)
}
```

in this situation, i have a type error with the object passed as parameter to the `f2` function by the `f1` function:

`Argument of type '{ _deletedAt: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TTest<T>'.`

but this shouldn't be, because `TTest` should accept any properties of its generic, which `_deletedAt` is

Strangely enough, in this updated exemple i have no error:

```
function f2<T extends Deletable>(param: TTest<T>): void {
  console.log(param)
}

f2<Deletable>({ _deletedAt: new Date() })
```

Nor in this one:

```
function f1<T extends Deletable>(param: TTest<T>): void {
  f2<T>(param)
}

function f2<X extends Identifiable>(param: TTest<X>): void {
  console.log(param)
}

f1({ _deletedAt: new Date() })
```

So here i am, with no clue as of what's going on

Does someone knows what's happening here and how to fix it ?

### EDIT

As requested, here is a more fleshed out situation where this behavior happens

This is not exactly the original code as i'm not allowed to share it, but it is very close and everything i believe to be relevant is present

```
class DBClass<T> {
  public find(query: object): T {
    return query as T
  }
}

interface Identifiable {
  _id: string
}

interface Deletable extends Identifiable {
  _deletedAt?: Date
}

interface Vehicle extends Deletable {
  _horsePower: number
}

abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends Identifiable> {
  private readonly DB: DBClass<T>
  protected constructor() {
    this.DB = new DBClass()
  }

  public findBy(query: TTest<T>): T {
    return this.DB.find(query)
  }
}

abstract class AbstractDeletableRepository<T extends Deletable> extends AbstractRepository<T> {

  public findActivesById(id: string): T {
    return this.findBy({ _id: id, _deletedAt: undefined })
  }
}


class VehicleRepository extends AbstractDeletableRepository<Vehicle> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
```

in this exemple, the object passed to the `findBy` method by the `findActivesById` methods raises the same error:

`Argument of type '{ _id: string; _deletedAt: undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TTest<T>'`

Comment: @jcalz the first code snippet i posted is the minimal reproducible exemple i could find.

As for the `DBClass` in my edit, it's a dummy class i created for the more fleshed out exemple, there is nothing in it.
The snippet in my edit is a code i wrote specifically to post here, for helpers to have more context as of how i really encountered this strange behavior as it is very close to how the real code is and work, but it is not the real code and as such there is nothing in `DBClass`.

In the real code i use the `typegoose` module to connect to a mongoDB database instead of `DBClass`

Comment: I think this is ultimately the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59279796/2887218).  Generic conditional types like `TTest<T>` when `T` is an unresolved generic type parameter aren't "understood" by the compiler, they are essentially opaque.  Even if you explicitly craft it so that you can assign a value to it when `T` isn't resolved, the compiler won't let you.  The easiest approach is to just use a type assertion and move on, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbaMbN). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz sadly that would defeat the point of this type, which is to have property name completion and verification

but i think there is no other way than your to make the compiler happy about this. At least i learned something.

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: The point of that type is to provide such completion and verification *inside subclass implementations*?  Then maybe [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mMOGzw) is a better way of using type assertions for that purpose.  Shall I write up that version instead?